# Recursion, out of memory?

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a function with two parameters. One is an empty string and the other is a string word. My assignment is to use to recursion to reverse the word and place it in the empty string. Just as I think ive got it, i received an "out of memory error". I wrote the code so that so it take the word, turn it into a list, flips it backwards, then places the first letter in the empty string, then deletes the letter out of the list so recursion can happen to each letter. Then it compares the length of the the original word to the length of the empty string (i made a list so they can be compared) so that when their equivalent the recursion will end, but idk

```
def reverseString(prefix, aStr):  
    num = 1  
    if num > 0:  
        #prefix = ""  
        aStrlist = list(aStr)  
        revaStrlist = list(reversed(aStrlist))  
        revaStrlist2 = list(reversed(aStrlist))  
        prefixlist = list(prefix)  
        prefixlist.append(revaStrlist[0])  
        del revaStrlist[0]  
            if len(revaStrlist2)!= len(prefixlist):  
                aStr = str(revaStrlist)  
                return reverseString(prefix,aStr)
```

Comment: this doesn't look like valid python function definition. is there a formatting problem near the bottom with the if statement?

Comment: You can't place letters in an empty string; strings are immutable. When the function returns, whatever changes you've made to the parameter disappear with that (local) variable.

Answer (score 2):

When writing something recursive I try and think about 2 things

1. The condition to stop the recursion
2. What I want one iteration to do and how I can pass that progress to the next iteration.

Also I'd recommend getting the one iteration working then worry about calling itself again. Otherwise it can be harder to debug

Anyway so applying this to your logic

1. When the length of the output string matches the length of the input string
2. add one letter to the new list in reverse. to maintain progress pass list accumulated so far to itself

I wanted to just modify your code slightly as I thought that would help you learn the most...but was having a hard time with that so I tried to write what i would do with your logic.
Hopefully you can still learn something from this example.

```
def reverse_string(input_string, output_list=[]):
    # condition to keep going, lengths don't match we still have work to do otherwise output result
    if len(output_list) < len(list(input_string)):
        # lets see how much we have done so far.
        # use the length of current new list as a way to get current character we are on
        # as we are reversing it we need to take the length of the string minus the current character we are on
        # because lists are zero indexed and strings aren't we need to minus 1 from the string length
        character_index = len(input_string)-1 - len(output_list)
        # then add it to our output list
        output_list.append(input_string[character_index])
        # output_list is our progress so far pass it to the next iteration
        return reverse_string(input_string, output_list)
    else:
        # combine the output list back into string when we are all done
        return ''.join(output_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(reverse_string('hello'))
```

This is what the recursion will look like for this code

```
1.
character_index = 5-1 - 0
character_index is set to 4
output_list so far = ['o']
reverse_string('hello', ['o'])

2.
character_index = 5-1 - 1
character_index is set to 3
output_list so far = ['o', 'l']
reverse_string('hello', ['o', 'l'])

3.
character_index = 5-1 - 2
character_index is set to 2
output_list so far = ['o', 'l', 'l']
reverse_string('hello', ['o', 'l', 'l'])

4.
character_index = 5-1 - 3
character_index is set to 1
output_list so far = ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e']
reverse_string('hello', ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e'])

5.
character_index = 5-1 - 4
character_index is set to 0
output_list so far = ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
reverse_string('hello', ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'])

6. lengths match just print what we have!
olleh
```